# Is it safe to share your root login details to server with an IT guy?

Tags: server

I'm trying to find help with my website where images aren't displayed for some reason and the whole site looks like a plain text document.

I've contacted an IT guy on Fiverr in a messenger and he told me not to place an order with him first, but give him root login details to my server and to C-panel. 
I'm just thinking is it safe to do so? 
I just started learning about building websites and don't understand all nuances yet. 
Thank you!

Comment: If you trust him, then I dont see an issue with it.  However, given that this is "some guy from Fiverr", I would be very VERY cautious about how much information you give him.  Ideally, you should try and fix the problem yourself.  Based on your post, I'd suggest that either rewrites aren't working, or permissions are wrong.

Comment: Assuming you're using Apache, can you please post the output of this command: `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer! I'm a total dummy, not aware of what you are asking me to do.

Comment: I think you are right about rewrites. My friend just let me use her website's files and I just bought my own domain name. Her site works fine, but mine has issues.

Comment: Ok, so open your terminal (if your on Ubuntu, that's the black box with the white text in it), then type `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log`.  This will display a list of errors associated with your Apache installation.  Use your mouse to highlight the errors, right click and copy, then edit your original question and paste the errors in there. I can clean it up if it gets messy.

Answer (score 3):

No. It is ***Never*** safe to give out a `root` password. Giving some "guy on Fiverr" your `root` details seems wrong.

First, Ubuntu doesn't (by default) allow `root` logins via password, but uses `sudo` instead. You shouldn't have a `root` password to give out.

Second, by asking for the `root` password, rather than a `sudo`-enabled user account makes me wonder if the "guy on Fiverr" knows Ubuntu, or if he's just going to stir your system with a `root`stick until/if it works.

Third, after granting `root` access, how will you track the changes the "guy on Fiverr" makes to your system? `sudo` (if you disallow `sudo su`, `sudo bash`, etc) keeps a history.